# cfinsert is picking up my search input field in a different form

Tags: forms, coldfusion

When I submit my form I am getting an error from my `cfinsert` function because there is not a database column name "SEARCHFIELD". The problem is "SEARCHFIELD" is not an input in the form I am submitting.

Both forms have close and open tags so I am not sure why my search form input is being referenced in my main forms submission?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it the name of your submit button or a hidden form field?

Comment: Both forms?  Are they submitting to the same page?  If so, do you have any conditional logic code on that page so you know what form is being submitted?

Comment: Can you dump the FORM object and check whether 'SEARCHFIELD' is coming to submitted page.

Comment: Because `cfinsert`....don't use it. It causes issues (like you have seen).

Comment: A) you are probably defaulting it somewhere (look for a cfparam) and B) as Scott says, cfinsert is not a good choice. Learn to write SQL. Cfinsert was created for ColdFusion 101 courses so HTML designers could learn a bit of CF without having to know anything about databases :)

Comment: I have no problem writing the SQL statement. In this case I have 120+ form inputs each with their own column name. I thought in this case cfinsert made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I can think of to avoid this, without seeing your actual code it is hard to guess where SEARCHFIELD is coming from.  As some of the comments pointed out it would most likely be from a CFPARAM or the name of your submit button in the form.

The first way you could tackle this is the CFINSERT tag has an attribute named formfields where you can list off the columns you wish to insert with.  You can see that here in this doc link:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c78.html

Another way you could do this is you could add code to remove SEARCHFIELD from the FORM scope prior to running the CFINSERT.  Which would be as simple as:

```
<cfset StructDelete(FORM, "SEARCHFIELD") />
```

You could check to see if it exists and if so then delete it but the StructDelete() will run without issues even if the field does not exist.

I personally do not use CFINSERT/CFUPDATE and I know the default opinion in the community is not to.  They do have some benefits though that often are overlooked in that they do parameterise the SQL and offer at least some safety from malicious people.  Without knowing anything about what you are doing it is hard to say if using them is actually a shot in your foot in the long run or something just fine to be doing.

Comment: Thanks for the great information outlined above. The main reason I am using cfinsert is because the form has 120+ inputs so...I hate to say I was trying to take the lazy way out. I have already wasted enough time where I could have written everything out. cfinsert seems too buggy already I just wanted to give it a try.

Comment: Since it is a one time event, why not just use the information_schema to generate the query param statements? We used to do [something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb6e7/16/0) in a legacy app with really large tables. I do not have the original handy, but that should give you are starting point, and it is reusable - just plug in the table and schema names.

Comment: .. because cfinsert is really a legacy tag. It has been years since I have touched it, but my recollection is it was buggy and hard to troubleshoot back then. Sounds like it has not changed.